# Display List in View in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, razor

I have a List with has three values.I want to display in view.Here is my approach

```
My Controller Function


public List<Movie> Index()
    {
        Movie obj = new Movie();
       return obj.ShowData();
    }
```

My model class & Function

```
 Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("MyDBLINK");
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

 public List<Movie> GetData()
    {
        try
        {
            DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("SP");

            DataSet dsResult = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand);

            List<Movie> Prop = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Movie>();
            Prop = (from DataRow row in dsResult.Tables[0].Rows
                    select new Movie
                    {
                        ID = Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"].ToString()),
                        Title = row["Title"].ToString()
                    }).ToList();
            return Prop;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Here is my view

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.List<MvcFirst.Controllers.MoviesController>

 @foreach (var item in Model)
{
<ul>
    <li>@item.ID</li>
    <li>@item.Title</li>

</ul>
}
```

My Question is how to display this list in View?
Secondly Is this approach is Good for CPU?

Comment: "Is this approach is Good for CPU" - The data has already traversed from the Server to your Client. Rendering it on the page in whatever form won't affect the CPU in a negative way. A `ListView` will come fro mthe style at which you display it. I'm assuming you're coming from a `WebForm` background? Depending on what type of List you want, you can Google for many styles.

Comment: @NewAmbition:Yes i am from WebForm background?What i can do here?Actually if it is as same then why do i need to learn that?Is that difficult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks almost fine, your controller should be something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var movie = new Movie();
   var result = movie.GetData(); // instance object and read the method to get the list
   return View(result);
}
```

An `ActionResult` could be any type of result, a View, a File to download, a Javascript, A StyleSheet, etc... but normaly is a View with the same name of action. If your action method is called `Index`, asp.net mvc will search for a View called `Index` on the `Views` folder. The part `return View(result);` means you are returning this View and passing the `result` object as a `Model` to your View.

Your `View` should be strogly typed with the entity (because you are returning it from the controller), not the controller:

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.List<Movie>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<ul>
    <li>@item.ID</li>
    <li>@item.Title</li>    
</ul>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've missunderstood how Controllers and Views work. Your Index() method need to return an ActionResult which will generate your view and return it to the user.

```
//My Controller Function

public ActionResult Index()
{
    Movie obj = new Movie();
    return View(obj.GetData()); //This will take the view with the same name as your method (Index in this case) and return it to the client/browser.
}
```

I hope I understood you question correctly.

Edit: I forgot to make the view stronly typed as Felipe Oriani has showned you